# GraalVM performance

Tags: java, benchmarking, microbenchmark, graalvm

We are evaluating GraalVM for our stack.
One of the major considerations is performance, and there are some benchmarks here: https://renaissance.dev/.

The problem is that we want to see benchmarks to implementations in other languages, not between OpenJDK and GraalVM versions.
The only I could find is in this article comparing it to C2. https://medium.com/graalvm/graalvm-20-1-7ce7e89f066b

Our google search turned up nothing else.

Where could we find more extensive, cross-language benchmarks of GraalVM?

Comment: are you looking for comparison with specific languages, like how GraalVM's JS engine compares to V8, or in general -- comparison of a Java program doing something vs. similar program in C# or some other language/runtime?

Comment: I would be curious to know GraalVM JS vs V8, but I'm really curious about native code generated by GraalVM from Java/Scala vs a similar program in C/C++ or even JS(V8). Thanks @OlegŠelajev for asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very complex question to be honest. It heavily depends on the workload, the language, etc.

Comparing implementations of the same language is kind of simple in comparison. For example, the [Renaissance suite](https://renaissance.dev/) does that for Java.

There's a very recent [presentation about Ruby](https://speakerdeck.com/eregon/running-rack-and-rails-faster-with-truffleruby), comparing TruffleRuby to CRuby on some web application benchmarks.

For JavaScript, if we look at Graal.js vs V8. One particular thing to note is that Graal.js has longer startup times. As in significantly longer. Currently you need to warm up the code quite a bit, sometimes minutes. The GraalVM team is working on improving startup, but some warmup will most probably be still needed.
In general, on our benchmarks performance after warmup is sort of comparable to V8, usually a bit slower.
If you want that particularly in the context of web applications, you can look not only on node.js apps, but for example [es4x](https://github.com/reactiverse/es4x) project.
Why I'm bringing that up, because for example the TechEmpower benchmarks that simulate real world scenarios by making the entries implement a predefined web-application with a database access and test it on several scenarios, have the results by languages. Here's the latest results filtered by JavaScript: https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r19&hw=ph&test=composite&l=zik0sf-1r

Es4x's score is better by almost 2x, and their submission does run on GraalVM, see [the docker file for their submission](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/frameworks/JavaScript/es4x/es4x.dockerfile#L1)

I don't know of any direct comparisons between GraalVM native image apps vs. node.js or C/C++ (though I'd imagine golang would be more interesting than c++ to compare to). The startup time & memory consumption would definitely be comparable: starting in a few dozen/hundred milliseconds, comfortably running in 128/256M environments.